# Conditional 'using'

Tags: c#, if-statement, using

I have the following code that does some conversion from one file to a memory stream which I then write to disk. All is working fine, however I now want to still always open `file_1` for reading, but either open `memory_stream` or `file_2` for writing based on user preference.

How can I get a conditional statement working in this situation given the braces will clash.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```cs
public static void ProcessFile()
{
   try
   {         
      using (Open file_1 for reading)
      using (Open memory_stream for writing)
      {
         ...
```

Comment: Does `using (Stream stream = [create whatever stream the user wants here])` work?

Comment: Don't get paralyzed by the first *using* statement not having any { braces }.  Just add them, now you have room to add an if-statement.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that?

```
public static void ProcessFile()
{
    using (Open_file_1_for_reading)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            using (Open_memory_stream_for_writing)
            {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `using` is just syntactic sugar for `try...finally`, where in `finally` `Dispose` method of `IDisposable` object (used in `using`) is called, so something like

```
try
{
  using(...){...}
}
```

makes little sense, as it will be seen as

```
try
{
  try{...}
  finally{dispose of an object}
}
```

I think you problem is simple, just do:

```
if(user preference)
{
  using(writing){...}
}
else
{
  using(reading){...}
}
```

Comment: `using` is _not_ just syntactic sugar for try..finally! The `using` block calls `.Dispose()` on the used object too.

Comment: @AKX You're right, I find that obvious, but still, it is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create separate methods for doing those two things. You should also have a method that handles the writing. These should not all be done by `ProcessFile`.

```
private static void WriteToFile2() {
    using (FileStream s = ...) { WriteToStream(s); }
}

private static void WriteToMemory() {
    using (MemoryStream s = ...) { WriteToStream(s); }
}

private static void WriteToStrem(Stream s) {
    ...
}

public void ProcessFile() {
    using (FileStream s = ...) { // file 1
        ...
        if (...) {
            WriteToFile2();
        } else {
            WriteToMemory();
        }
    }
}
```